# AutoCAD Undefined Shape; Style dialog crashes

Tags: c#, autocad

I am developing an application in C# for AutoCAD 2014.  When I run AutoCAD under the VS2013, if I draw a dimension I get "Undefined shape **" [** is a two digit number].  If I try to open the STYLE menu, the program crashes.  In writing text, it cannot find the font.

All this said, if I run AutoCAD outside of VS, everything works fine.  In searching problems one pointed to the face AutoCAD could not find the font files.  However, it seems to since outside of Visual Studio everything works fine.

Anyone have an idea? Programming in AutoCAD works OK, I just cannot put text to the AutoCAD window.

Comment: I'm trying to determine if you're attempting to create dimensions natively using C#, or if you're simply trying to pass the dimension command to the command line through C#.  Could you clarify on this, as well as provide some of the code you've tried so far?  I'm sure many here would nudge you in the right direction if we knew what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be because of a problem with x64 bit edit and continue incompatibility when running Visual Studio 2013.  Try one of two things:

1. Turn on “Use Managed Compatibility Mode” via Tools –> Options –> Debugging.
2. Turn on “Enable native code debugging” from Project –> Properties –> Debug.

Kean Walmsley expands on this in his latest blog post:

http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2013/11/debugging-autocad-using-visual-studio-2013.html

Comment: Number 1 worked, Managed Compatibility Mode.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Same for me - #1 was enough, I didn't need to `Enable native code debugging` - in fact it tried to load symbols for everything inside AutoCAD...life is too short for that.